# Can React Native dynamically switch the language of the system soft keyboard?

Tags: react-native

Excuse me,My requirement is to dynamically switch the language of the soft keyboard on IOS or Android. The premise of switching is that the user manually adds a certain language to the soft keyboard. I just want to switch the existing language.

Looking forward to reply, thank you very much!

If React Native can do it please tell me how?
If you can't do it, please tell me why it can't be done, I need to tell the boss why it can't be done!

Comment: Typically, keyboard language settings are managed by a device's operating system. Because the React Native app would need to communicate with the underlying OS to make the change, changing those settings within the app could be difficult and time-consuming.

Comment: In other words, as a framework, React Native does not expose the Api provided to developers to operate the underlying layer (Android or IOS), so it is almost impossible to use RN.